# Rails Nested Attributes form_for for has_many with unlimited nested models using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've got a pretty simple model with nested attributes set up:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trees
  accepts_nested_attributes for :trees
end
```

Then I build them in my controller:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @property = Properties.new
    @trees = @property.trees.build
  end
end
```

And then in my view (using slim):

```
= form_for @property |p|
  = p.text_field :name

  .tree
    = p.fields_for :trees do |t|
      = t.text_field :fruit
      = t.select :quantity, (1..1000).to_a

    = link_to 'Add Another Tree', new_properties_path, id: 'new-tree'
```

And then in my js (coffeescript) file, bound to the click event of the '#new-tree' anchor:

```
event.preventDefault()
tree = $(event.target).parents('.tree')
tree.after tree.clone(true)
```

This works as you would expect, however when I submit the form, only the last tree params get submitted. This is because in the generated html of the form_for I get something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="property_trees_attributes_0_fruit" name="property[trees_attributes][0][fruit]">
<select id="property_trees_attributes_0_quantity" name="property[trees_attributes][0][quantity]" class="valid">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  ...
</select>
```

And when I clone this html I get the name and id with the `0` in it, though I believe it should be a `1` to add additional tree params, etc.

I tried to compensate with the js by doing something like this:

```
event.preventDefault()
tree = $(event.target).parents('.tree')
clone = tree.clone()
number = parseInt(clone.find('input[type=text]').attr('id').match /[0-9]/)
next = number + 1
clone = clone.html().replace /_(#{number})_|\[(#{number})\]/, next
section.after clone
```

The point of the regex is to replace any numbers between two underscores or two brackets, like `_0_` or `[0]`

My regex doesn't seem to work though. It replaces `_0_` with just `1` and this solution seems messy to me anyways. I would make the regex simpler, however then I have to worry about it changing the value of the select menu options.

Any suggestions for cleaning this up? Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is you're just duplicating DOM elements - this is IMO a hack, as you're not building the objects you need before-hand (won't persist the data etc)

We've implemented an "add extra fields to `f.fields_for`" using Ajax before - there's a [great tutorial here](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/) and a [RailsCast here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

---

**child_index**

The answer to your question is to use the `child_index` option in the `fields_for` helper, and to make that use an `integer` timestamp:

```
<% index = Time.now.to_i %>
<%= f.fields_for :trees, child_index: index do |fields| %>
    #your fields here
<% end %>
```

---

**Code**

Here's what we do:

```
#app/views/properties/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "trees_fields", locals: { f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i } %>
   <%= link_to "New Field", new_field_property_path %>
<% end %>

#app/views/properties/_trees_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :trees, child_index: child_index do |trees| %>
   <%= trees.text_field :your_attr %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/properties_controller.rb
def new_field
    @property = Property.new
    @property.trees.build
    render "add_tree", layout: false
end

#app/views/properties/add_tree.html.erb
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
      <%= render partial: "trees_fields", locals: {f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i} %>
<% end %>

 #app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
$ ->
  $(document).on "click", "#add_tree", (e) ->
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax
       url: '/messages/add_subscriber'
       success: (data) ->
              el_to_add = $(data).html()
          $('#trees_form').append(el_to_add)
       error: (data) ->
          alert "Sorry, There Was An Error!"
```

Comment: This is great! The worst part is I have a railscast subscription, I just totally didn't know these ones existed. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem! Hope you gained from it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are right, nested `.tree` elements shouldn't have the same id. So you shouldn't clone them. Instead build new item using helper, generate id based on current time for instance and then paste new nested element. This is a complex scenario, so I think it would be better to watch related railscasts:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised